# Unable to get string using gets() in C

Tags: c, string, gets

I wanted to write a program to check which string has a greater length without using string functions. I tried to get the two strings as input using `gets()` but my program keeps on crashing. Please help! Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int l1,l2;
char *st1,*st2;
void accept()
{
    gets(st1);
    gets(st2);
}
void length()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (st1[i] != '\0')
    {
        l1++; i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (st2[i] != '\0')
    {
        l1++; i++;
    }

}
int main()
{
    accept();
    length();
    if (l1 > l2)
        printf("String #1 is greater in length.\n");
    else
        printf("String #2 is greater in length.\n");
}
```

Comment: st1 and st2 don't point to anything.

Comment: Does this code compile without warnings? Does it run without producing an error?

Comment: Here comes my favourite quote of all man pages: "**Never use `gets()`.**" Because it's impossible to use safely.

Comment: I often find it amusing how the difference between `printf` and `fprintf` is an extra `FILE*` but the difference between `gets` and `fgets` is a `FILE*` _and_ a length. Amusing in a sad way that is

Comment: @DanielFischer: What's the alternative to gets()?

Comment: "Use `fgets()` instead." says the man page.

Comment: "The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by size from the
     given stream and stores them in the string str.  Reading stops when a newline character is found, at
     end-of-file or error.  The newline, if any, is retained.  If any characters are read and there is no
     error, a `\0' character is appended to end the string." -- From the manpage

Comment: I've updated my original answer to reflect the use of `fgets` as a safer alternative to `gets` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have not allocated space to `st1` or `st2` nor have you initialized them... so they are both pointing to some unknown place in memory. Try...

```
char st1[1024];
char st2[1024];
```

That said, realize that `gets` is inherently unsafe as it is subject to buffer overrun attack; there's nothing to stop someone from entering a string longer than 1024 and crashing your program.

You can also greatly simplify the length() function as follows...

```
void length()
{
    for (l1 = 0; st1[l1] != '\0'; l1++ );
    for (l2 = 0; st2[l2] != '\0'; l2++ );
}
```

Expanding on this and your question about what's an alternative to `gets()`, the answer is to use something like `fgets()` -- for example...

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( fgets( st1, sizeof( st1 ), stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        if( fgets( st2, sizeof( st2 ), stdin ) != NULL )
        {
            length();

            if (l1 > l2) printf("String #1 is greater in length.\n");
            else if (l2 > l1) printf("String #2 is greater in length.\n");
            else printf( "Both strings are the same length.\n" );
        }
        else printf( "could not read second string\n" );
    }
    else printf( "could not read first string\n" );

    return( 0 );
}
```

In this case, `fgets()` will not allow the user to overflow `st1` or `st2` and it will ensure they are always null terminated strings.

Answer (score 1):

use `l2` in the second `while` loop,

```
    l1=0;
    while (st1[l1] != '\0')
    {
        l1++;
    }
    l2 = 0;
    while (st2[l2] != '\0')
    {
        l2++;
    }
```